# AngularJS 1.2.0 ngBindHtml and trustAsHtml not working with ngModel

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I feel like this should be really easy since I had it working perfectly with Angular 1.0.8 using ngBindHtmlUnsafe. I read on the API docs and on StackOverflow that I need to use `$sce.trustAsHtml()` with `ngBindHtml` now but I cannot seem to get it to work.

This is basically the format I am using given what I read:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function myController($scope, $sce){
    $scope.myHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.sourceText);
}
```

html:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.0-rc3" data-semver="1.2.0-rc3-nonmin" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <textarea ng-model="sourceText"></textarea>

      <div ng-bind-html="myHtml"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I thought it would be this straightforward but I must be wrong and missing something.

I dropped this simple example to a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZX4dONBlzv1X8BcO1IBV?p=preview

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?
http://plnkr.co/edit/IZkzsuKHvbYiyV07CGqp

```
// would strongly suggest including sanitize in your scripts and injecting it
// into your app here to prevent "unsafe as safe" errors
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$sce', function myController($scope, $sce){
  $scope.myHtml = "initial";  //not needed, for testing

  $scope.changeText = function() {
    $scope.myHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.sourceText);
  }
}]);
```

Html:

```
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.0-rc3" data-semver="1.2.0-rc3-nonmin" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <textarea ng-model="sourceText" ng-change="changeText()"></textarea>

      <div ng-bind-html="myHtml"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for but for some reason when I do the same in my app (reformatting controller and adding the new function, etc) my console is now giving me this error: `Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngClass', can't be found!` which doesn't make immediate sense to me since ngModel and ngClass are part of core...

Comment: @ryanlutgen How to do  reverse of your solution, for example: i have html code already which is assigned to $scope variable. which is used in ng-model. so i want to display that in textarea not as code, but as text.
(For summernote editor)