# angular: create formating filter without html-escaping

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-escape

I want to do automatic html formatting for some strings.
For example, I want to do automatic subscripts for a char that is prefixed with an underline.
So a string like "U_1 + U_2 = U_3" 
should be formatted to  U<sub>1</sub> + U<sub>2</sub> = U<sub>3</sub>

This looks like a perfect job for a filter. I tried the following:

```
angular.module('myApp.filters', []).
  filter('convert_subscripts', [ function(){
      return function(text){
          return text.replace(/_([\w]+)/, '<sub>$1</sub>', 'g');
      };
   }])
```

And in my view:

```
<p>{{content.text | convert_subscripts }}</p>
```

But this escapes the HTML, so the user sees the "sub" tags instead of a nicely formatted subscript.

How do I implement a formatting function so that the html-Tags are not escaped?

(To be perfect, the content.text itself should be escaped for security, but the added subscript-tags not. I use angular 1.2)

Comment: Try this: `<p ng-bind-html="content.text | convert_subscripts"></p>`

Comment: @codeHater: That gives me an runtime error: Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0/$sce/unsafe 
I think there was some changes in angular 1.2.

Comment: Oh right. You would need to inject `$sce` service into your controller and call the `$sce.trustAsHtml` method. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625850/angularjs-1-2-0-ngbindhtml-and-trustashtml-not-working-with-ngmodel

Comment: Yes, this worked (I injected $ice in the filter definition).

Answer (score 0):

[I think this article should help.](http://www.ekiras.com/2015/03/how-to-escape-html-in-angular-js.html)
 You can render the html as it is by two ways

```
$sce.trustAsHtml('text')
```

or you can create a filter for this purpose like

```
app.filter('filterName',function($sce){
    return function(text){
             $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
           }
    });
```

In your case you should use approach 1

```
function($sce){
      return function(text){
          return $sce.trustAsHtml(text.replace(/_([\w]+)/, '<sub>$1</sub>', 'g'));
      };
```