# Using jquery in angular in returning data from $http.get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I make an `$http.get` request to apache server and the response is an HTML page. I would like to use jquery to some data from the HTML page.

The code of my controller is:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.showImages = function() {
        $http.get('http://localhost/images/').success(function(data) {
            $scope.images = data;
        });
    };
}]);
```

I can see that in `$scope.images` is stored the html page that return from server but I do not have a clue how to use jquery to extract e.g the value of all href appeared in the page.

Comment: DO u want to show image from server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract any information, you can achieve directly from data. Just add data type for the call and use jQuery(data) to access html

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.showImages = function() {
        $http.get('http://localhost/images/',
         dataType: "html").success(function(data) {
          // Now use this html Object as normal object and retrieve information 
          var htmlObject = jQuery(data);
          $scope.images = data;
       });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I guess that I have to use $http  not $http.get in order to add data type.

Comment: I don't understand how to retrieve e.g all td tags from that object.

Comment: With respect to above code, htmlObject.find("td") will give you the array of all the td tags.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to parse HTML before doing any manipulation. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141080/angularjs-http-html-parser) SO post.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show image then you only need path/url of  image from server not image data or HTML.